# How to perform bucket filtering with ElasticSearch date histogram value_field

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to construct a date histogram with ElasticSearch logs of the following type:

```
{
    "_index": "foo"
    "_source": {
    […]
    "time": "2013-06-12T14:43:13.238-07:00",
    "userName": "bar"
    }
}
```

where the histogram buckets the "time" field per "day" interval, but also where multiple occurrences of a single userName only gets counted once.

I have tried the following:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "facets" : {
        "histo1" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "key_field" : "time",
                "value_script" : "doc['userName'].values.length",
                "interval" : "day"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where I have expected the min|max|mean for each of the "histo1" entries to be the number of unique users in the respective time buckets. But the result consistently returns `min = max = mean = 1`

```
    "histo1": {
        "_type": "date_histogram",
        "entries": [
            {
                "time": 1370908800000,
                "count": 11,
                "min": 1,
                "max": 1,
                "total": 11,
                "total_count": 11,
                "mean": 1
            },
            {
                "time": 1370995200000,
                "count": 18,
                "min": 1,
                "max": 1,
                "total": 18,
                "total_count": 18,
                "mean": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

Am I misunderstanding how key/values works in date histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the elasticsearch timefacets plugin: https://github.com/crate/elasticsearch-timefacets-plugin

Other options included:

- https://github.com/bleskes/elasticfacets
- https://github.com/ptdavteam/elasticsearch-approx-plugin

Both of them only have support for ES version < 0.90, unfortunately.